# very slow internet connection

Tags: performance, internet

I have a netgear router and the internet strength says its excellent but when i try to play online on my xbox it is very slow and only have one bar connection. And i have noticed that when it goes slow the wifi light on my router blinks extremely fast. But sometimes it dont blink and i can play on my xbox just fine and then it will start blinking fast again and the internet will be going slow again. Someone please help me! What is wrong with my internet?

Answer (score 0):

Then it's not your internet, it's Wi-Fi, Something is Taking over the Wi-Fi Bandwidth, Like copying files, etc.

if you provide me your router model i will see if i can diagnose this better.

Comment: It says N300 wireless ADSL 2 modem router with ethernet WAN DGN2200v4

Comment: Im not sure if thats the model or not. I just really need to knowhow to fix this cause im in a really big clan on call of duty. Im not sure if your familiar with it or not but i got to record my gameplay and i cant do that with slow internet so please help me

Comment: I'd try the obvious.. move the xbox closer (at least to test) to the router... get a full strength signal.  that tells us if we can eliminate low signal strength.  Also what is the label on the light that blinks fast?

Answer (score 0):

There are some factors that can cause this, let me tell you some of them.

1. I dont know how Xbox works at all, but if it is connected via a cable make sure that cable is not damaged, because the blinking on (Also I dont know what every info does cable pass) router can also mean a data loss or also Xbox since it would had slow connection try to use maximum of your router.
2. **The servers you play on** - There may be also an issue of that, the server is way far from you and your provider may not have good connectivity to handle it without packet loss.
3. **Router is used so much** - You have mentioned that it blinks, but that may not mean that it wasnt used a lot before, but it may also mean that when u started to play it was used just really much, so make sure that not hard transfers are done during you are playing

Aswell I wanted to list more probable causes but realized that it is really hard to get to problems as that.